# GS1 etiquetas Code128 subset C

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Alguém implementou o padrão código de barras GS1?
 No padrão existe um código de barras Code128. 
Estou tentando implementar utilizando o Code 128 subjet C, minha quantidade de dígitos vai ser impar. 
 Como tem que ser:

```
1517072011170323703007607271023031701
```

Mas ele esta ficando assim:

```
01517072011170323703007607271023031701
```

Alguém sabe uma forma de contornar isso, algum componente ou alguma forma de montar manual o código de barras? Pois devo imprimir um código ímpar e tem que ser Code128C.

Tentei utilizar os Subjet A e Subjet B, mas o código gerado é muito grande não atende minha necessidade.
Esses códigos de barra vai para o cliente, não tem como eu ajustar no programa.

Estou utilizando Delphi XE7 - Fortes Report - TRLBarcode.

Answer (score 0):

Ao ler código de barras o ideal é fazer filtro que tanto pode ser no scanner quando no seu programa.

O normal é fazer no programa, pois além de alguns modelos de scanner não fazerem filtro, no programa a leitura chega 100% pura.

No seu exemplo acima é só ignorar o primeiro dígito que no caso é 0.